# Compression of ODB files

Tags: java, compression, lossless-compression

I have a requirement to compress large ODB files which measure >1GB. I have used LZMA algorithm and could compress upto 22%.
Is there a better way to compress these types of files with better compression ratio?
The compression has to be loss-less.

Comment: You could venture a try into Arithmetic Coding (http://nayuki.eigenstate.org/page/arithmetic-coding-java) but though it will likely be better than LZMA, it's probably not worth your effort to upgrade just with entropy compression. If you know that the contents will almost always be English (compresses to 15% from ANSI), you could probably achieve a better compression ratio using a markov model with pre-loaded statistics. I expect though that your database also has a lot of numeric information, which don't compress well. Perhaps 20% is about the best you can do.

Comment: I tried Arithmatic coding. But, it is showing the exception saying 'total' is too large. I there a way to increase 'MAX_TOTAL' so that large files be compressed?

Comment: Without knowing your code, I have no way of knowing what 'total' is or does for you. Think of a way of storing that >1GB. It's basically just one high-precision float, but you probably don't want to store it all in memory at the same time (Don't use `BigDecimal`). So, you'll need to write parts of it to a file and then shift the bits of the rest.